# Need drawLayer to draw 3 PDF files to 3 different UIViews

Tags: xcode, pdf, calayer, draw, catiledlayer

I am loading 3 different PDF files and drying to use drawLayer to draw them into 3  UIviews. This works, but they are all 3 being drawn into the same layer of one UIview.  I need them each drawn into their own UIView, but I can't figure out how to parse this code up into three parts.  Any ideas please?

```
// This method takes care of the cropping and adds each PDF layer to the view
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context));
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(mappageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, mappageRef);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(vorpageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, vorpageRef);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(labelpageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, labelpageRef);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A CALayer belongs to a single UIView and is responsible for drawing just itself, not other layers. You need the controller to send each PDF file to the correct view, and have each view draw it in its own layer.

Comment: I follow you. How would I assign the drawLayer above to a UIView called mapView, for example. Is there an opening tag preceding the code above that I could use to assign the draw even to a specific UIView?

Comment: You would never do this in the middle of a `drawLayer:inContext:`. That's a drawing method. And it shouldn't even be within this view class. You need to do this in the view controller that owns these views. It's responsible for passing the data to the views, and the views pass the data to their layers.